# LALR(1) parsers and the epsilon transition

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers

I am having trouble getting my head wrapped around epsilon transitions while creating an LALR(1) parse table.

Here's a grammar that recognizes any number of 'a' followed by a 'b'. 'S' is an artificial start state. '$' is an artificial 'EOS' token.

```
0.    S -> A $
1.    A -> B b
2.    B -> B a
3.    B -> epsilon
```

Itemsets:

```
i0: S -> . A $
    A -> .B b
    B -> .B a
    A -> B . b  ! because B could -> epsilon
    B -> B . a  !    "

i1: S -> A . $

i2: S -> A $ .

i3: A -> B . b  ! from i0
    B -> B . a

i4: A -> B b .  ! from i0 or i3; the LALR algorithm compresses identical states.

i5: B -> B a .  ! from i0 or i3: the LALR algorithm compresses identical states.
```

I previously had a description on how this would work to parse a simple string. I removed it because I know less now than I did before. I can't even figure out a parse tree for 'ab'.

If someone could show me how I have mis-constructed my itemsets and how I'd reduce the epsilon transition I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your states and itemsets are not quite correct. The epsilon production must appear in relevant itemsets, and you have combined two states into one, which would produce a shift-reduce conflict if the epsilon production were added to the itemset (which should be done).

The following was generated with bison (using the `--report=all` command-line option); it differs from the theoretic model because the grammar has been "augmented" with an extra start symbol and an explicit end-of-input marker (`$end`). Also, it has done some table compression, so in the action tables, you can think of `$default` as meaning "either `a` or `b`".

It is worth explaining how State 0 comes about, since it shows how epsilon productions are handled (no differently from other productions).

We start with `$accept: . S $end`, by definition. (`$accept` is the starting state). Then the closure rule is applied as long as possible. Remember that the closure rule is: If any item in the itemset, the `.` is immediately before a non-terminal, add all the productions for that non-terminal with an initial `.`. Hence we add:

```
S: . A
```

continuing with `A`:

```
A: . B 'b'
```

continuing with `B`:

```
B: . B 'a'
B: .
```

We can't apply closure any longer, so we're done. Since the state now has an item with the dot at the end (the epsilon production for B), a reduction is possible.

```
State 0
    0 $accept: . S $end
    1 S: . A
    2 A: . B 'b'
    3 B: . B 'a'
    4  | .

    $default  reduce using rule 4 (B)    
    S  go to state 1
    A  go to state 2
    B  go to state 3

State 1
    0 $accept: S . $end

    $end  shift, and go to state 4

State 2
    1 S: A .

    $default  reduce using rule 1 (S)

State 3
    2 A: B . 'b'
    3 B: B . 'a'

    'b'  shift, and go to state 5
    'a'  shift, and go to state 6

State 4
    0 $accept: S $end .

    $default  accept

State 5
    2 A: B 'b' .

    $default  reduce using rule 2 (A)

State 6
    3 B: B 'a' .

    $default  reduce using rule 3 (B)
```

In State 0, the closure rule has added the epsilon production (line 4). Furthermore, no item in the state 0 itemset has the point before a terminal. So with *any* lookahead, the parser is forced to reduce the epsilon production, after which it will use the `goto` function for state 0 to decide to move to state 3. (In your state machine, states 0 and 3 are conflated, but I do not believe this is correct.) State 3 will definitely shift a terminal; with the input `ab$end`, it will shift the `a` and move to state 6, which will then reduce a `B`. And so on.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to this. I have slightly amended my question; I had an artificial start state already (S). I added the artificial EOI token. The description I had was non-sensical so I removed it.

Comment: ok, I just reread this again. I think per the LALR algorithm, conflating identical states happens. It's actually one of the reasons LALR algorithm makes smaller tables though at some cost - a full LR parser would generate fewer shift/reduce or shift/shift errors.

Comment: The idea that the epsilon transition ends up in state 0 is new to me. Compare to my post. This means that a 'GOTO' would be applied (and why not? there is a 'dot' at the end of the closure...) I was assuming that we had to shift first. I must cogitate on this for a while.

Comment: @TonyEnnis: The epsilon production is no different from any other production, so it gets added by the closure production. However, the closure construction does not add `A -> B . b` because the closure construction does not examine non-terminals to see if they are nullable. I will make the answer more explicit in a bit.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have a handle on it now. But if you're bored, please add more detail! I have thought about this some, and I did not think to consider the epsilon as terminal. You were correct in thinking I considered it something that would modify the LALR algorithm. It still may a little later, but not during itemset construction.